# The document "doc.xml" does not have a valid root (REXML::ParseException)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to convert an XML document into a Ruby hash for the first time, and having no success. I have my XML document, `doc.xml`, in a folder along with my script `hashrunner.rb`.

In `hashrunner.rb`:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash'
hash = Hash.from_xml("doc.xml")
puts hash
```

The first line of the XML document is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>`, if that is helpful.

In my console, when I run `ruby hashrunner.rb`, I get the error message:

```
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/xml_mini/rexml.rb:34:in `parse':The document "doc.xml" does not have a valid root (REXML::ParseException)
```

As someone relatively new to Ruby, I don't understand what this means, and some internet searching didn't turn up an explanation, either. To start, I'm not even sure if I'm calling the XML file correctly in the `from_xml` method, so please let me know if that's the case. I'd be open to using different gems or a different approach if that would help.

Comment: It looks like there is an error in doc.xml somewhere past the first line. Make sure it has exactly one top-level element. Adding the first few lines of the file might help.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that's it: I've been trying this with various XML files, even those of the most basic kinds (including an entirely empty XML document).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `Hash::from_xml` has to take an XML string, not a filename string. Try:

```
hash = Hash.from_xml(File.read("doc.xml"))
```

Comment: WOW, thanks a ton, kardeiz. Super simple fix that worked perfectly, and I didn't see that info anywhere else online.